# the date format is asking to enter data in dd-mmm-yyyy format, how can I change it to ddmmyy

Tags: oracle, date, oracleforms

I'm newbie and I'm making Forms with *Developer 6i*, but the date format is asking to enter data in **`dd-mmm-yyyy`** format.

How can I change it to **`ddmmyy`** then I press Enter button so as to make it **`dd-mm-yyyy`**.

eg. I entered **`120622`** then its need to become **`12-06-2022`**.

Hope you will get it.

I tried but gets nothing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using "6i"?  It is 20+ years old and hasn't been supported for over 15 years.  If you are trying to learn, doesn't it make sense to learn the new version (12.2.1.4)?

Regardless, if your issue is related to working with a text field/item, simply set the Format Mask for that field to "dd-mm-yyyy".   Now when you enter something like 03012023 (Jan 3, 2023) you will see 03-01-2023 when you exit the field.

[image]